# Python Selenium - unable to interact with the save button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

The html snippet for my page:

[image: html snippet]

I've tried using the button id as well as a css locator but I keep getting the element not found error. I tried combining the click with the explicit wait but that did not work either.
Also tried using the img tag to see if that worked. Got the same issue

Please let me  know if I'm missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not attach code as an image. Please read  ['How do I ask a good question?'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the 'Help center'.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the element using the text like this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Save']").click()
```

please note that it shouldn't be another clickable part in the page that has the "Save" text

Answer (score 0):

First grab the element. Make sure it is displayed. Then fire the click event.

```
save_button_element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='//*[text()='Save']')

if save_button_element.is_displayed():
    save_button_element.click()
```